# How can I use APS development certificate in a release build?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, apple-push-notifications

There is a bit of black magic in Xcode concerning builds configurations. It makes a lot of work for us but at the same time all settings are not easy to find for specific customization.

I would like to make a release build of my app for one simple reason: I'd like to test it with some test users in testflight without having dev-specific UI showing up.

We have debug tools in the app for when we build in DEBUG mode.

Our server (dev server only for now as we didn't release yet) does use the APS development certification.

So I'm simply trying to push a testflight version that looks like our production app but using the Debug APS certificate. How can I do that ?

**Changing manually the entitlement file to APS > production ?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not use it, Some concerns are

1. You can't submit an Archive over iTunesConnect with development certificate and development profile.
2. And if you are using Enterprise certificate OR Production certificate then during Archive process system will search for production APS certificate in keychain.

So for testing purpose you can either use Enterprise certificate to distribute it among random USERS on your own server OR you need to upload a distribution version with production certificate over itunes connect while having Production APS in keychain. You need to use "gateway.push.apple.com:2195" in your APNS server setting rather than "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195".